# canvas - how to set interval in requestAnimationFrame() loop?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

i was looking for how to stop a loop in requestAnimationFrame() loop.

I'm trying to make a simple top-to-bottom falling circle animation and every time the circle hit the bottom, in this case the window.innerHeight, it will set its position back to its starting position then wait until 12 sec to animate again. i'm trying to use setTimeOut() but the circle got faster instead.

this is my code:

```
drawCircle = () => 
{
    requestAnimationFrame(this.drawCircle);
    this._CONTEXT.clearRect(0, 0, this._CANVAS.width, this._CANVAS.height);
    this._CONTEXT.beginPath();

    this._CONTEXT.arc(this.x, this.y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    this._CONTEXT.lineWidth   = 1;
    this._CONTEXT.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
    this._CONTEXT.fill();

    this.y += 15;        

    if (this.y > this._CANVAS.height) {
        setTimeout(12000);
        this.initPos();
    }
}
```

Comment: nevermind, misread the question ... setTimeout exepects `(fn, timeout, optional args...)` as arguments ... you are not using it correctly

Comment: If you don't want your code to run right away, don't call `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: okay, thank for your correction ..